# Lua: delete specific characters in a string

Tags: string, replace, lua

I have a string that includes all the characters which should be
deleted in a given string. With a nested loop I can iterate through
both strings. But is there a shorter way?

```
local ignore = "'`'"  

function ignoreLetters( c )
  local new = ""
  for cOrig in string.gmatch(c,".") do
    local addChar = 1
    for cIgnore in string.gmatch(ignore,".") do
      if cOrig == cIgnore then
        addChar = 0
        break  -- no other char possible
      end
    end
    if addChar>0 then new = new..cOrig end
  end
  return new
end

print(ignoreLetters("'s-Hertogenbosch"))
print(ignoreLetters("'s-Hertogen`bosch"))
```

The string `ignore` can also be a table if it makes the code shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) to replace any occurance of a given string in a string by another string. To delete the unwanted characters, simply replace them with an empty string.

```
local ignore = "'`'"  

function ignoreLetters( c )
  return (c:gsub("["..ignore.."]+", ""))
end

print(ignoreLetters("'s-Hertogenbosch"))
print(ignoreLetters("'s-Hertogen`bosch"))
```

Just be aware that in case you want to ignore magic characters you'll have to escape them in your [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).
But I guess this will give you a starting point and leave you plenty of own work to perfect.